# Kafka Streams - Processor schedule punctuator by cron expression

Tags: java, cron, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

`ProcessorContext.schedule(..)` accepts duration interval parameter, and we could specify that some action (punctuator) will be executed every X time interval (e.g. every hour). With such scheduling, execution time depends on the last application restart time. And additionally, if we have multiple instances of application, and only app on single node was restarted (e.g. due to some prod issue), punctuators will be executed at absolutely different times on each node. For some use cases it might be not applicable, and it's needed to execute punctuator by cron expression, like with `"0 0 * * * ?"` execute every hour, approximately at time `XX:00:00`.

**Is it possible to schedule punctuator by cron expression?** or does exist any workaround? 
As a dirty workaround, we could  calculate  time interval from now till upcoming first execution of cron inside `Processor.init(..)`, and on first triggering of punctuator, cancel existing scheduling and create a new one, converting from cron expression to duration instance. seems such workaround is error prone.

Comment: I assume there is some library to convert cron into `ms`, but it's not like you'd be able to do `0/5` expression for example, so I don't see the point

Comment: This is not possible atm and I also cannot come up with a good workaround. There is a ticket for this request already: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7699